# Detection of Lattice Homomorphism.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

If $(L,*,+)$ and $(S,\cdot,\vee)$ are two lattices, a mapping $g\colon L\to S$ is called a lattice homomorphism from $L$ to $S$ if for any $a,b \in L$ we have $g(a*b) = g(a) \cdot g(b)$ and $g(a+b) = g(a) \vee g(b)$.

I can't understand what $g(a*b) = g(a) \cdot g(b)$ and $g(a+b) = g(a) \vee g(b)$ means. How can we detect homomorphism between two lattices?

Comment: Can you explain a little more just what’s not clear to you about $g(a*b)=g(a)\cdot g(b)$ and $g(a+b)=g(a)\lor g(b)$?

Comment: I can understand that $(a * b)$ is GLB of a and b and $(a + b)$ is LUB of a and b. Whats $g(a*b)$ = $g(a)$ . $g(b)$ ?

Comment: It’s really the condition that for **all** $a,b\in L$, the map $g$ sends the GLB of $a$ and $b$ in $L$ to the GLB of their images $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ in $S$, and similarly for LUB.

Comment: Can you explain giving an example. What are images? I am writing below what I understand.
Let L = {1,3,9} and S = {2,4,8} under relation "divides". Then g(1)=2 , g(3)=4 and g(9)=8 ? $g(3*9) = g(3) = 4 = g(3)*g(9) = 4*8 = 4$ .  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right, provided that $g$ is the map that sends $1$ to $2$, $3$ to $4$, and $9$ to $8$; $2,4$, and $8$ are the images of $1,3$, and $9$, respectively, under this map. I’ll write up a slightly less trivial example for you.

Comment: So are the lattices L = {1,3,9} and S = {2,4,8} under relation "divides" homomorphic? If they are homomorphic then I think that they are also isomorphic as the function is one-one and onto.

Comment: Yes, that map is actually an isomorphism. Every isomorphism is a homomorphism, but not conversely; I’m in the process of writing up an example of a homomorphism that is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be the lattice $\langle\wp(\{a,b\}),\cap,\cup\rangle$, and let $S$ be the lattice $\langle\{0,1\},\land,\lor\rangle$, where $m\land n=\min\{m,n\}$ and $m\lor n=\max\{m,n\}$. Define $g:\wp(\{a,b\})\to\{0,1\}$ as follows: for each subset $X$ of $\{a,b\}$, $g(X)=1$ if and only if $a\in X$. The four elements of $\wp(\{a,b\})$ and their images under $g$ are shown in the following table.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
X&g(X)\\ \hline
\varnothing&0\\
\{a\}&1\\
\{b\}&0\\
\{a,b\}&1
\end{array}$$

Now let’s check that $g$ is a lattice homomorphism. Suppse that $X,Y\subseteq\{a,b\}$; we need to show that

$$g(X\cap Y)=g(X)\land g(Y)\tag{1}$$ and $$g(X\cup Y)=g(X)\lor g(Y)\;.\tag{2}$$

You can verify this by brute force: there are only $4^2=16$ possible pairs of $X$ and $Y$ to check. However, brute force isn’t really needed. I’ll take $(1)$ first.

- Suppose that $g(X\cap Y)=0$; that means that $a\notin X\cap Y$, so either $a\notin X$, or $a\notin Y$ (or both). If $a\notin X$, then $g(X)=0$, and if $a\notin Y$, then $g(Y)=0$, so at least one of $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ is $0$. This of course implies that $g(X)\land g(Y)=0$, which verifies $(1)$ for this case.
- If instead $g(X\cap Y)=1$, then $a\in X\cap Y$, so $a\in X$ and $a\in Y$. But then $g(X)=1$ and $g(Y)=1$, so $g(X)\land g(Y)=1\cap 1=1$, and we’ve verified $(1)$ for this case as well. There are only these two cases, so we’ve actually proved that $(1)$ holds for all $X,Y\in\wp(\{a,b\})$.

$(2)$ is proved similarly, so I’ll be a little more concise.

- If $g(X\cup Y)=0$, then $a\notin X\cup Y$, so $a\notin X$ and $a\notin Y$. Thus, $g(X)=0=g(Y)$, and $g(X)\lor g(Y)=0\lor 0=0$, and we’ve verified $(2)$ for this case.
- If $g(X\cup Y)=1$, then $a\in X\cup Y)$, so at least one of $X$ and $Y$ contains $a$, and at least one of $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ is $1$. That implies that $g(X)\lor g(Y)=1$, so $(2)$ holds in this case as well, and we’ve completed the proof that $g$ is a lattice homomorphism.

Note that since $g$ is not a bijection, it certainly isn’t a lattice isomorphism. It ‘collapses’ the power set lattice to the two-element lattice, distinguishing subsets of $\{a,b\}$ only as to whether they contain $a$ or not instead of looking at all of their elements.

Comment: I can't understand the mapping between L and S. I understand that g(∅) = 0 and g({a,b})=1 but how is g({a})=1 and g({b})=0 ?

Comment: @user221458: Because that’s the way I defined the map $g$. It was my choice. Of course I did it in that way because I knew that doing so would give me a homomorphism, but it was still just a choice on my part. I could just as well have defined the map $f:\wp(\{a,b\})\to\{0,1\}$ by $f(X)=1$ if and only if $b\in X$; that gives me a different homomorphism.

Comment: What if mapping is not given? Don't we have to create mapping based on the level of element in the lattice? In the following example : L = {1,3,9} and S = {2,4,8} under relation "divides". I have mapped g(1)=2 , g(3)=4 and g(9)=8 because according to the relation divides 1 <= 3 <= 9 and similarly 2 <= 4 <= 8 .

Comment: @user221458: Notice that my homomorphism $g$ splits the middle level of the power set lattice: $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are on the same level, but $g$ sends the first to $1$ and the second to $0$. An isomorphism must preserve levels, but a homomorphism need not do so. If you’re not given a map from a lattice $L$ to a lattice $S$, it may be very difficult to determine whether there is a homomorphism $g:L\to S$.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Does isomorphic lattices have the same Hasse diagram? This should be the case as it preserves the levels and also its bijective. I may be wrong though. Also is equality on Z a lattice?

Comment: @user221458: You’re welcome. Yes, isomorphic lattices have the same Hasse diagram. Do you mean, is equality a lattice ordering on $\Bbb Z$? No: no two distinct elements have a join or a meet with respect to equality.

Comment: And is order preserving and level preserving the same thing?

Comment: Also on this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Morphisms_of_lattices is written that "Any homomorphism of lattices is necessarily monotone with respect to the associated ordering relation". What is monotone and monotonic mapping?

Comment: @user221458: Yes, if you mean *strict* order-preserving. If you just mean that $x\le y$ implies that $g(x)\le g(y)$, then no: all lattice homomorphisms have that property, but you’ve seen that they need not preserve levels. *Monotone* means what I just wrote: $g$ is monotone if $x\le y$ implies that $g(x)\le g(y)$.

Comment: Ok. One last question : For what values of n the set of divisors of n under partial order relation divides is a chain?

Comment: @user221458: Suppose that $n$ has two distinct prime factors $p$ and $q$; then $p\nmid q$ and $q\nmid p$, so you don’t get a chain. What positive integers are divisible by at most one prime?

Comment: Primes itself and powers of primes?

Comment: @user221458: Yep, and also $1$, which gives you the trivial lattice.